# Will I be refused entry even though I have a new passport?

Tags: turkey, denial-of-entry

Five years ago I was refused entry into Turkey because I had the wrong visa.
At the time, I had a British Overseas Citizen passport.
My husband had a British Citizen passport. We both had the same visa.  My husband was granted entry and I was not.
We both live in England.

My question is, will I be refused entry because I have been refused before?

I now have a British Citizen passport and I know that visas are no longer required, but will I be refused entry because I have been refused before?  Do I need some clearance from Turkish Embassy?

Comment: The typical advice to clear up a past run-in with Immigration is to apply for entry clearance (i.e. a visa). Were you given any paperwork at the time? What visa did you have when you were refused entry?

Comment: Traveller is correct: apply for a visa. But I'm confused about what happened five years ago. You had a visa, official permission issued by Turkey to enter the country. The visa was in your British Overseas Citizen passport, so Turkish Immigration knew the type of passport because they had it in their hands when they issued the visa. Why were you refused entry? Was the wrong visa mistakenly issued to you? Something else?

Comment: My British Overseas Citizen passport was not considered British.  The first time I had no problems.  They probably thought I lived somewhere else not in England!

Comment: I had the visa for a British national. The same one my husband has.  Will they issue me with a visa if one is not required for a now British passport?

Comment: @Audrey Having a citizenship that makes you eligible for visa-free entry does not preclude you from applying for any visa to anywhere. As an aside, a check via Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&modify=1  returned different visa requirements when selecting ‘British Overseas Citizen’ and ‘British Citizen’ as the travel document held, which may possibly account for your previous entry refusal.

Answer (score -2):

Having a different citizenship passport should result in not being blocked due to having had a 'wrong' passport to enter the last time.
Just a new passport would not change anything, it is the different citizenship that makes the difference.
And as you are still the same person, you will have to admit not being allowed into the country in the past.

If you are worried about it you can apply for a visa or at least a 'leave to enter' from the embassy/consulate before setting out. With one of those your history will be checked before you are at the border and you will be sure about the old problem being solved before you get to on the plane.

(For 2020/2021 travel, check the COVID 19 rules as well, as many countries have restrictions and those change all the time.)